# ODBC: ERROR [28000] Invalid OAuth access token when connectig to Snowflake from Power BI using SSO

Tags: powerbi, single-sign-on, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I tried to setup a connection from Power BI Desktop to Snowflake, using SSO. I followed the instructions as described here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-powerbi.html

So, I did the following:

In Snowflake I ran the following, where <AZURE_AD_ISSUER> was replaced by https://sts.windows.net/ + Our Azure AD Tenant ID + /

```
create security integration powerbi
    type = external_oauth
    enabled = true
    external_oauth_type = azure
    external_oauth_issuer = '<AZURE_AD_ISSUER>'
    external_oauth_jws_keys_url = 'https://login.windows.net/common/discovery/keys'
    external_oauth_audience_list = ('https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/connector/Snowflake')
    external_oauth_token_user_mapping_claim = 'upn'
    external_oauth_snowflake_user_mapping_attribute = 'login_name';
```

When trying to connect from Power BI Desktop I get the following error:

Unable to connect

We encountered an error while trying to connect.
Details: "ODBC: ERROR [28000] Invalid OAuth access token.

I also tried `external_oauth_snowflake_user_mapping_attribute = 'email_address';` but without success.

Anyone got an idea where this can go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, you can check two things:

1. Verify that the external_oauth_issuer parameter contains the correct value
2. Verify the access token in Azure AD is current

For more error messages regarding PowerBI SSO to Snowflake see here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-powerbi.html#error-messages

Also another hint: I saw this once and a simple update of PowerBI solved the problem.